# How to create data-list for multiple input fields on the form? HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html-datalist

I have form with about 50 fields that should have same options for user to select. I was looking over datalist in HTML5. Looks pretty good because gives the option to user to type in desired option from the list. I was wondering if there is an option to apply same data list to all 50 fields. Only examples that I found so far use `id` attribute. Is there a way to create this with JQuery/Javascript and apply the same class to all fields? I have tried but didn't work, my input fields are empty and no error in the console. Here is my example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
     for(var i=0; i <= 120; i+=5){
      $('#hzIntervals').append("<option value='" + i + "'>");
     }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" list="hzIntervals" size="3" />
<datalist id="hzIntervals" style="width:20px;"></datalist>
```

Above code will produce datalist with an option only for one field. Also I set width on datalist but still I see more width once I click on my input field. I would like datalist width to match input field width (size=2). If anyone knows how to achieve that please let me know. Also I'm open for any suggestions.

Comment: can you create fiddle for this?

Comment: offtopic: dont append everytime to a new jquery object html. Its better to store the html in a variable and append after the loop.

Comment: you only have to add the attribute list="hzIntervals" to all the other input fields: https://jsfiddle.net/yfd5c2nw/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the input fields point to the same datalist . So just add the list attribute with the same value to all your fields:

```
<input type="text" list="hzIntervals" size="3" />
<input type="text" list="hzIntervals" size="5" />
<datalist id="hzIntervals" style="width:20px;"></datalist>
```

check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yfd5c2nw/3/

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't create `datalist` element in JQuery? I see in your example you added attribute list using JQuery.

Comment: no I just posted what needed! your code for generating the datalist is right! you can keep it! I did too in my fiddle

Answer (score 0):

datalist works with ID and there isn't another way to connect the list with the input field.

However, you can change the script to work with all the datalist, but keep in mind that every input and datalist have to have an unique ID.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for(var i=0; i <= 120; i+=5){
        $('datalist').append('<option value="'+i+'">');
    };
});
```

Have a look at https://fiddle.jshell.net/d5xjczvc/

Cheers.

Comment: @Daiele Do I need datalist for every input element? Can just one be created in JQuery and then use the id in the attribute list for each input field?

Comment: You can use more inputs for the same datalist but you cannot use more datalist with the same input

Comment: What about creating this in JQuery? Is that an option?

Comment: see my jsfiddle! you have to only set the attribute to all your inputs

Comment: @MarouenMhiri maybe I'm wrong, but he needs just one input with multiple datalist

Comment: hmm! no the question is about having multiple fields pointing to the same datallist